# Radius affects the covariant derivative?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $S^2(R)$ be the $2$-sphere with radius $R>0$. Then one can write in spherical coordinates the Christoffel symbols which do not depend, at least explicitly, on $R$ (see [here](http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/general-relativity/34-christoffel-symbol-exercise-calculation-in-polar-coordinates-part-ii) for the computation).

My question is: selecting a small neighbourhood of the sphere, say around the north pole, and taking $R\gg1$, how can I see the effect of the curvature becoming flat in the covariant derivative, since it only depends on the Christoffel symbols? The base vectors $\partial_\theta$ and $\partial_\varphi$ becomes larger with respect to the pullback metric (by a factor $R$ I believe). Does it play any role?